# Launch a .jar multiple times with different parameters

Tags: batch-file

I've got 2186 jpeg files that I need to convert into another filetype with a specific program. Unfortunately, I'm very bad when it comes to batch files, but here's what I have so far:

```
java -jar -Xmx1024m convert.jar -d2 -h64 -w64 -s Untitled_000000.jpeg output_000000.schematic
```

It takes file Untitled_000000.jpeg and converts it into output_000000.schematic . How would I go around making it convert 2186 files automatically, up to output_002185.schematic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

#### Main.bat

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 2185) do (Pad.bat "%%a")
```

And in the same directory:

#### Pad.bat

```
set var=%1
:loop
set var=0%var%
if "%var:~5,1%"=="" goto :loop

java -jar -Xmx1024m convert.jar -d2 -h64 -w64 -s Untitled_%var%.jpeg output_%var%.schematic
```

And that will should work for you. (I have tested it)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. There is an issue with

    "set var=%1"

- Syntax error.

I tried to change it to

    "set /a var=var+1"

It works, but it only works up to 000008 and resets to 000000.

Comment: try it again with two spereate batch files

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off


setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd C:\pics_dir
for /l %%L in (Untitled_*.jpeg) do (
    set "file_name=%%~nL"
    set "current_number=!file_name:~9!"
    java -jar -Xmx1024m c:\convert.jar -d2 -h64 -w64 -s "%%~L" output_!current_number!.schematic
)

endlocal
```